# jquery problem with animate function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I animate a div with jquery. You can see my animation here. On the bottom of the page you click on the call me button. Now you see a animation that i make with jquery. http://www.mikevierwind.nl/test/

Now my animation going wrong. I used this jquery code for the animation.

```
nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = true;
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('actief');
            $("#formulier-callme").animate( { width:"375px" }, 1000 )
                .animate( { height:"270px" }, 1000 )
```

But the animation going wrong. Now he animate on the top the first animation. But i want that he animate on the bottom the first animate.

How can i make that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: your question isn't clear enough to answer. Can u explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

No worries!  You are just chaining together animation functions that should instead be callbacks within the previous animation:

```
nieuwsbrief_formulier_open = true;
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('actief');
        $("#formulier-callme").animate( { height:"270px" }, 1000, function(){
            $(this).animate( { width:"375px" }, 1000 );
        });
```

You can also get more information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686207/jquery-animate-chains-callbacks-and-stoptrue-true) about jQuery animations